# Find the best solution for read file and call web service

Tags: file-io, iterator

I have a text file which has about 100,000 records of identifier.

I must read all of record, each record i do request to web service and receive the result from web service, the result i write to another file.

I'm confuse between two solution:
- Read identifier file to a list of identifier, iterate this list, call web service, ....
- Read identifier line on each line, call web service, .....

Do you think what solution will be better ? program will do faster ?

Thanks for all.

Comment: How about read the file and call the web service in parallel?

Comment: you mean we can't call the web service while read file ? I do when reading each line, I get the value and send to the web service.

Comment: I mean in one thread we do: "read a line, send to another thread, read a line, send to another thread,..." and in the other thread: "receive a line, send to web service, receive a line, send to web service, ...".

Comment: How complex are the operations made throught the web service for the records? Are they almost real time (miliseconds)? They take seconds, minutes?

Comment: @Dukeling: Because read file is very fast, and calling the web service is slow. So i think your solution is not effective. Do you think so ?

Comment: @Coral Doe: I don't need the real time, only combine two task how to quickly. Thanks

Comment: I was talking about how long are the web service calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dukeling says, using different threads to read the file, send requests and write to file can increase the speed of the program, rather the one thread solutions you propose.

I recommend that you would start using asynchronous calls to your web service. You make the call, but don't wait for a response (you handle the responses in the callback). When you make a lot of calls to the web service in parallel (as you want speed), this frees up some I/O threads on your hosting machine and can improve the rate/time of processed requests sometimes.
Then you can have a thread that reads from the file, starts the asynchronous call and repeats. On the callback function you implement the writing to file. You should at this level implement a logic that insures that your responses are written in the right order.

On the other hand, calling the web service for each record may be too chatty.
I would suggest an implementation similar to pagging: loading a certain amount of records, sending them to operation and receiving the responses in bulk. You should take care of not failing the whole package for one recors, have a logic for resending only a part of the tasks and so on.

Comment: Thank you. It a good solution. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e15184/asynch.htm